# Slow DNS lookup only on certain ISPs (CentOS 6 Server)

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns

**Greetings to fellow community members!**

I had moved to Liquidweb about 2 months back (Cloud Dedicated Server). I only have a few low traffic sites (6-7) on the server. Immediately after the move, I saw a weird phenomenon when accessing my site from Airtel ISP (one very large ISP in India).

a) The browser would remain stuck at "waiting for domain.com" for about 15 seconds, and then site would suddenly load
b) This behavior would happen on all airtel connections (tested from different devices and connections).
c) In the meanwhile, the domain liquidweb.com would load normally, i.e. it was not a universal problem.
d) The problem was not observed on other ISPs (obviously, I could not test them all).

The tech team at LW tried switching DNS from BIND to POWERDNS, but it did not help (I still left it at POWERDNS though)

After a lot of digging on external forums, one person asked me to change the WHM > Networking > Resolver Configuration, and asked me to change the IPs to google's DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

This instantly fixed the delayed DNS lookup problem via Airtel connections!

After that long introduction, here are my questions for your kind help!

**i) Should I leave DNS on POWERDNS or revert to BIND?**

**ii) Is it "Safe" to use google public DNS in the resolver configuration?** Any downsides to this? Some tech folks told me many hosting companies use this all the time. Are there any Email Blacklisting issues while using open public resolvers? (Context : following comment I saw somewhere "*One thing to mention, some RBL's will actually block access to some open resolvers sometimes, which results in all email being tagged as blacklisted.*")

**iii) Are there any other similar server settings I should be checking**, as I had moved from a VPS to a Cloud Dedicated Server? I am a complete newbie, and someone told me there are lots of settings / areas which should be looked at, when moving to a dedicated server. e.g. I had learnt of modsec and checked some rules which were creating issues.

Would be very grateful for any advice & help!

Amit

Comment: There are numerous corner cases in the DNS standards that are handled differently by the various software implementations. If you wish to receive further assistance, please provide a list of the domains you were experiencing issues with before switching to 8.8.8.8.

Comment: It may be an IPv6 problem. Does Airtel provide IPv6?